# How To Fix "TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment"

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, tkinter, nonetype

I tried to make a login window but when I press submit button in window instead of the values getting appended in file its shows `TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`
And I also want that when I press submit button the thankyou window opens but it opens as soon as I start the program.

My Code

```
counter=1
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl


wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet=wb.active
sheet["A1"]="Name"
sheet["B1"]="Guardian Name"
sheet["C1"]="DOB"
sheet["D1"]="Age"    
sheet["E1"]="Address"
sheet["F1"]="Contact Number"
wb.save(filename="Login.xlsx")
def submitvalue():
    global counter
    wb=openpyxl.Workbook("Login.xlsx")
    sheet=wb.active
    sheet[f"A{counter+1}"]=name.get()
    sheet[f"B{counter+1}"]=guardian.get()
    sheet[f"C{counter+1}"]=Dob.get()
    sheet[f"D{counter+1}"]=Age.get()
    sheet[f"F{counter+1}"]=Address.get()
    sheet[f"G{counter+1}"]=contactnumber.get()
    counter+=1
    thankwin.mainloop()    
root=Tk()
root.geometry("444x555")
# Heading
Head=Frame(root)
Head.pack(fill="x")
Label(Head,text="Login Form",fg="white",bg="red",font="k 23 bold italic underline").pack(fill="x")

# Login fixed text
main=Frame(root)
main.pack()
Label(main,text="Name",font="arial 15",justify="left").grid(row=0,column=0)
Label(main,text="Guardian Name",font="arial 15",justify="left").grid(row=1,column=0)
Label(main,text="Date of Birth",font="arial 15",justify="left").grid(row=2,column=0)
Label(main,text="Age",font="arial 15",justify="left").grid(row=3,column=0)
Label(main,text="Address",font="arial 15",justify="left").grid(row=4,column=0)
Label(main,text="Contact Number",font="arial 15",justify="left").grid(row=5,column=0)


# Creating entry widgets
name=StringVar(root)
guardian=StringVar(root)
Dob=StringVar(root)
Age=IntVar(root)
Address=StringVar(root)
contactnumber=IntVar(root)


Entry(main,textvariable=name).grid(row=0,column=1)
Entry(main,textvariable=guardian).grid(row=1,column=1)
Entry(main,textvariable=Dob).grid(row=2,column=1)
Entry(main,textvariable=Age).grid(row=3,column=1)
Entry(main,textvariable=Address).grid(row=4,column=1)
Entry(main,textvariable=contactnumber).grid(row=5,column=1)
Button(main,text="Submit",command=submitvalue).grid(row=6,column=0)

# Footer
Footer=Frame(root)
Footer.pack(side="bottom",fill="x")
Label(Footer,text="Contact Number:",fg="blue").pack()
# Thanku window
thankwin=Tk()
Label(thankwin,text="Thank You").pack()
Button(thankwin,text="OK",command=exit).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__      
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Tanmay\Documents\Programming\Tkinter\exercise.py", line 76, in submitvalue
    sheet[f"A{counter+1}"]=name.get()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: `sheet` is set to `None`, so you can't assign anything using item assignment syntax (`None[...] = ...`).

Comment: What should i do then? I am a beginner.

Comment: The problem is in `submitvalue`.  After opening `"Login.xlsx"`, `wb.active` is `None`.  So don't try to use it.  You should probably add a check for `wb == None` (or `wb is None`) before attempting to access it.

Comment: did u try putting entry and corresponding grid in separate lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace  wb=openpyxl.Workbook("Login.xlsx") with openpyxl.load_workbook("Login.xlsx") in submitvalue

Comment: It didn't show error but also the data was not appended in file.

Comment: @TanmayDaga It is because you didn't call `wb.save("Login.xlsx")` after inserting data to the worksheet.